# unable to open sqlite3 database in QT

Tags: linux, qt, sqlite

I am in the beginning phase of both sqlite, as well as QT.
There are various examples under QtSDK IDE for sqlite database. This is an excerpt from one of the examples :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
if (!db.open()) {
    QMessageBox::critical(0, qApp->tr("Cannot open database"),
        qApp->tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                 "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                 "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information how "
                 "to build it.\n\n"
                 "Click Cancel to exit."), QMessageBox::Cancel);
    return false;
}
```

This works just fine. but if I try to replace ":memory:" with an actual sqlite3 database file,...

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    accounts_db = new QSqlDatabase();
    *accounts_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE"); perror("");
accounts_db->setDatabaseName("/home/aditya/test.db.sqlite");
QSqlError *a = new QSqlError();
*a = accounts_db->lastError();
perror(a->text().toLatin1());
if (!accounts_db->open()) {
    perror("database open error :");
    QMessageBox::critical(0,qApp->tr("db.open\n"),a->text(),QMessageBox::Cancel);
    goto end;   // quit if not successful
}
if ( !accounts_db->isOpen() ) {
    perror("database is not open");
}
query.exec("select accno,branchcode,fname,lname,curbalance,accdate from accounts");
while(query.next()) {
    QString str = query.value(0).toString();
    std::cerr << qPrintable(str) << std::endl;
}
end:
;
}
```

...then I am not so lucky. Not sure exactly how lastError() works, but tried it anyway. I am getting these errors...

```
No such file or directory
: Invalid argument
QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
```

I have tried changing the permissions n'all on the concerned files and folders as suggested on different forums, but to no results. Just a note, I am working on Ubuntu Linux (...if that matters), I have also tested this test.db database file with the sqlite3 command line program, that works flawless.
Any guidance is appreciated...thanks.

EDIT:

Very sorry that I completely forgot to explain what the error is... :|

Comment: I have no idea what's wrong but can you try to figure it out by using the lastError function? (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qsqldatabase.html#lastError)

Comment: I did try that but not able to actually print any error. Anyway, the perror prints "No such file or directory" for my database file. I have also tried putting the database in my home directory as suggested here (http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/CS001504_-_Creating_an_SQLite_database_in_Qt) , but that also does not seem to work...

Comment: I have no idea which file is it talking about when it says "No such file or directory"...   anyone ???

Comment: You should call `lastError()` after open.

Comment: I did, it gives _Invalid argument_ as above...

Answer (score 0):

Created a brand new database, and it works !!!

not clear why it was not working before though... I definitely need to study more.

Anyway, thanks a lot ppl :) .